# How to put something at the top of the \longrightarrow?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, stacking-symbols

I would like to put something at the top of the `\longrightarrow`, something like
`\longrightarrow^{k\rightarrow\infty}`. However, instead of putting `k\rightarrow\infty` on the top right corner, I would like to put it in the middle on the top of `\longrightarrow`. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In this instance, I think `\xrightarrow` would suit you better. Here's an example using the former, and the traditional `\overset` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}    
\[
  \mathcal{X}\overset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{Y} \qquad 
  \mathcal{X}\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}\mathcal{Y}
\]
\end{document}
```

`\xrightarrow{<stuff>}` is an extensible arrow, which conforms in length to the overset argument `<stuff>`.

Comment: And what if I want stuff on top and bottom of double/thick arrow: $\Rightarrow$. What if I want some text also below that arrow? Can I make it extensible arrow? (Am new to this site. Isnt this site use MathJax to render equations/Latex text netweem $$. Does content here apply equally to MathJax. I want to use these arrows on math.stackexchange. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial doesnt tell how to do that arrow stuff.)

Comment: @anir: In (La)TeX you can try [this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/X0benKnM). However, MathJax is not (La)TeX, so you'll have to find a different, probably convoluted, way to generate that.

Comment: Do \overset and \stackrel do the same thing?

Answer (score 19):

Use

```
\stackrel{k\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you want the long arrow to stretch you may prefer

```
\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I can accept only one answer. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: For anyone who missed it like me, you need to add reference \usepackage{amsmath} before you can use xrightarrow

Answer (score 2):

There is a great commend that allow you to put something on and under the `\longrightarrow`:

```
x \underset{down}{\overset{up}{\longrightarrow}} y
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: This is already covered in the other answers.